# Return value from a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I want to be able to set a variable with a simple var myVar = myFunction(); But myFunction has a callback inside of it and thus cannot return the value. I'm a bit lost on how I would convert this code to be able to return a value from the callback so that I could keep the simple variable definition.

```
#!/usr/bin/node
"use strict";
var http = require('http');

var myHappyVar = getTheData();
console.log(myHappyVar);

///// Functions /////
function getTheData() {
  var data = '';
  var options = {
    host: 'google.com',
    port: 80,
    method: 'GET'
  }

  http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
       data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
      console.log("DATA: " + data);
      return data;
    });
  }).end();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  AJAX requests are *asynchronous*, and their callbacks don't run until the request is done.  That will be in the future, way after the `getTheData()` function is done.

You are going to need to restructure your code.  You can pass `getTheData()` a callback to run once the data is ready, but you cannot have it *return* anything.

```
function getTheData(callback) {
  var data = '';
  var options = {
    host: 'google.com',
    port: 80,
    method: 'GET'
  }

  http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
       data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
      console.log("DATA: " + data);
      if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        callback(data);
      }
    });
  }).end();

}
```

Then you can do:

```
getTheData(function(myHappyVar){
  console.log(myHappyVar);
});
```